# Example of injecting services in Angular 1.5 components

Tags: angularjs

Can anyone give an example on using services with Angular 1.5 components?

I'm trying to inject a service in an Angular 1.5 component, but it doesn't work.

I have a login component like so:

```
class Login {
    constructor($scope, $reactive, $state, myService) {
        console.log(myService.somevariable); //doesn't work
    }
}

// create a module
export default angular.module(name, [
    angularMeteor
]).component(name, {
    templateUrl: 'imports/ui/components/${name}/${name}.html',
    controllerAs: name,
    controller: Login
});
```

My service looks like this:

```
angular.module(name).service("myService", function () {
    this.somevariable = 'somevalue';
});
```

I just cant seem to be able to get the service injected in the component.What am I doing wrong?

**SOLUTION:**

With [sebenalern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3103677/sebenalern)'s help, I got it working.

I needed a service to validate an email address using a regular expression. I did it like this:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import angularMeteor from 'angular-meteor';
class Validator { 
    validateEmail(email) {
        var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return re.test(email);
    }
}

const name = 'validator';

// create a module
export default angular.module(name, [
    angularMeteor
])

.service("Validator", Validator);
```

I then injected the service like so:

```
import {name as Validator} from '../../../api/services/validator'

class Login {
    constructor($scope, $reactive, $state, Validator) {
        'ngInject';
        this.$state = $state;

        $reactive(this).attach($scope);
        this.Validator = Validator;
    }

    login() {
        if(this.Validator.validateEmail(this.credentials.email)) {
            // email is valid. 
        }
    }    
}

const name = 'login';

export default angular.module(name, [
    angularMeteor,
    Validator
]).component(name, {
    templateUrl: `imports/ui/components/${name}/${name}.html`,
    controllerAs: name,
    controller:Login
})
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: What do you mean by component?

Comment: I've updated the question. I'm using an Angular 1.5 component, and I have no idea how to inject an Angular service in it. Since Angular 1.5 is new, I could not find any documentation either.

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: I updated my answer. I think it should help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So one problem I see is you should be using the keyword **this** inside the constructor

```
this.$scope = $scope;
```

Another thing it is probably easier to stay away from classes and use functions:

```
class Login {
constructor($scope, $reactive, $state, myService) {
    console.log(myService.somevariable); //doesn't work
   }
}
```

Becomes:

```
angular
.module('name')
.service('myService', myService);

function myService () {
    this.somevariable = 'somevalue';
}
```

To me it seems a lot cleaner. Also another thing about ES6 classes is

> ES6 Classes are not hoisted, which will break your code if you rely on hoisting

For more info see [link.](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/variable-and-function-hoisting)

Now here is the working code I came up with:

First we declare the module:

```
angular.module('name', []);
```

Next we register our service and then create the service definition:

```
angular
   .module('name')
   .service('myService', myService);

function myService () {
   this.somevariable = 'somevalue';
}
```

Next we do the same procedure for our controller and also we inject $scope and our service into it.

```
angular
   .module('name')
   .controller('Login', Login);

function Login($scope, myService) {
    $scope.someVar = myService.somevariable;
}
```

Last I registered our component:

```
angular
   .module('name')
   .component('my-html', {
   templateUrl: 'my-html.html',
   controller: Login
});
```

And that is it on the javascript side.

Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" ng-app='name'>
  <head>
      <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.1/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="controller.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body >
      <h ng-controller="Login">{{ someVar }}</h>
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps!!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in Angular 1.5. I've updated the question. I get an error `Error: myService is not defined`.

Comment: With your help I was able to get my code working, but in a slightly different way. I've posted my solution and accepted your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I am doing it and it works well. It works fine with classes. I assume you are using TypeScript.

```
class AdminHomeService {
    consignment: IConsignment;

    get: () => IConsignment;

    constructor() {
        this.consignment = new Consignment();
        this.consignment.id = 10;
        this.consignment.customer = "Customer3";
        this.consignment.customerList = [{ id: 1, name: "Customer1" }, { id: 2, name: "Customer2" }, { id: 3, name: "Customer3" }];
        this.consignment.shipperList = [{ key: "1", value: "Shipper1" }, { key: "2", value: "Shipper2" }, { key: "3", value: "Shipper3" }];
        this.consignment.consigneeList = [{ key: "1", value: "Consignee1" }, { key: "2", value: "Consignee2" }, { key: "3", value: "Consignee3" }];
        this.consignment.billingList = [{ key: "1", value: "Billing1" }, { key: "2", value: "Billing2" }, { key: "3", value: "Billing3" }];
        this.consignment.carrierList = [{ key: "1", value: "Carrier1" }, { key: "2", value: "Carrier2" }, { key: "3", value: "Carrier3" }];

        this.get = () => {
            return this.consignment;
        }
    }
}

class AdminHomeComponentController {
    consignment: IConsignment;
    selectedCustomer: any;

    static $inject = ["adminHomeService"];

    constructor(private adminHomeService: AdminHomeService) {
        this.consignment = new Consignment();
        this.consignment = this.adminHomeService.get();

        this.selectedCustomer = {};
        this.selectedCustomer.selected = { "name": this.consignment.customer };
    }

    customerAddClick(): void {

    }
}

class AdminHomeComponent implements ng.IComponentOptions {
    bindings: any;
    controller: any;
    templateUrl: string;
    $routeConfig: angular.RouteDefinition[];

    constructor() {
        this.bindings = {
            textBinding: "@",
            dataBinding: "<",
            functionBinding: "&"
        };
        this.controller = AdminHomeComponentController;
        this.templateUrl = "templates/admin.home.html";

        //this.$routeConfig = [
        //    { path: "/admin", name: "AdminHome", component: "adminHome", useAsDefault: true }
        //];
    }
}

angular.module("adminHome", [])
    .component("adminHome", new AdminHomeComponent())
    .service("adminHomeService", AdminHomeService);
```

This post helped me a lot: http://almerosteyn.com/2016/02/angular15-component-typescript